# php - regex to find a value of a div in text/javascript

Tags: php, regex

I have a JavaScript and I must to use regex to extract my wanted parts with php.

my javascript is:

```
gabjoorblock += '<div class="ganjoor-poem-block">';
gabjoorblock += '<div class="ganjoor-m1">یونیکد</div>';
```

I try this code to retrieve `"یونیکد"` but it don't work:

The code should be this:

```
$regex = '/<div class="ganjoor-m1">(.+?)<\/div>/s';
```

please help me.

Comment: You shouldn't parse HTML with regex if you don't want head banging bugs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#answer-1732454 :/ That may be linked. If the HTML is just what you show, your regex is working.

Comment: '/<div class="ganjoor-m1">([^<]*)<\/div>/s';

Comment: [`strip_tags()`](http://il1.php.net/strip_tags) is your friend!

Comment: @philipp it don't work

Comment: On the snippet you gave, it works. What is your full gabjooblock string? How do you apply your regex? Have you considered using the dom to retrieve what you want?